# expect tool and logical OR

Tags: linux, expect

i use `expect` command for my script. I have a few different prompt, and i need OR for expressions.

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
expect {
   'Hello. Press y for YES' *OR* 'Welcome again. Press y' {send -- "y\r" }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expect already has *or* built-in, eg:

```
expect {
  "Hello. Press y for YES"  {send -- "y\r"}
  "Welcome again. Press y"  {send -- "y\r"}
}
```

If the action is too big, you can put it in a function. But if you prefer you can use a regular expression *a|b*:

```
expect -re "Hello. Press y for YES|Welcome again. Press y"  {send "y\r"}
```